Plus/minus do not rotate with the component
How can I solve the problem of plus/minus do not rotate with the component?

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{/tikz/circuitikz/voltage/distance from node=0.3cm}
\draw
    (0,0) to [generic, v<=40<\volt>] (1,3);
\end{circuitikz}



\end{document}


Is this for a standalone image or is this part of a larger circuit?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it's of a large circuit.

No, they do not rotate by design --- reading a vertical - is not exactly straightforward. Given that tastes vary a lot, you can always use "advanced voltages" (section 5.8 of the manual), ask circuitikz to generate the anchors, and draw whatever you like...
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
    \ctikzset{label/align = rotate}
    \def\DIR{0,45,90,135,180,-90,-45,-135}
    \foreach \i in \DIR
    \draw[blue] (0,0) to[R, v=\i, *-o] ++(\i:4);
    \foreach \i in \DIR {
        \draw (9,0) to[R, v=\i, no v symbols, *-o, name=v\i, voltage shift=1] ++(\i:4);
        \node [rotate=\ctikzgetdirection{v\i}] at (v\i-Vfrom) {$-$};
        \node [rotate=\ctikzgetdirection{v\i}] at (v\i-Vto) {$+$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If you really, really want it, I suggest keeping the signs with the labels and rotating them too, as also suggested by @Chris H (but notice you have to take care of where the + is by hand, you can't use v< mechanism...)
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american, 
    declare function={mydir(\x)=\x>90?(\x>269? \x: \x-180):\x;}]
    \ctikzset{label/align = rotate}
    \def\DIR{0,45,90,135,180,-90,-45,-135}
    \foreach \i in \DIR
    \foreach \i in \DIR {
        \draw (9,0) to[R, v, no v symbols, *-o, name=v\i, voltage shift=1] ++(\i:4);
        \node [rotate={mydir(\ctikzgetdirection{v\i})}] at (v\i-Vlab) {$+$\quad\i\quad$-$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


sorry for the jagged image; okular is acting up again...

Thanks. You made me have to rethink what is actually better!

Somehow the m̶u̶l̶t̶i̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶i̶g̶n̶s̶  45° plus signs are even worse than the aligned minus signs!  But it might be better if the labels (angles here but normally of the form "R1" or "4k7") were aligned to the components as well; that would guide the reading direction

Yes, you can do this --- and probably the better way would be to use "raised American" style in that case. But IMHO bipoles should be mostly horizontal or vertical, and the test should be horizontal whenever possible.
